# Method to return username and Id

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Hi guys im trying to get Username And id, right now im just getting the id.

This is the Stored Procedure:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spLogin] 
    @username VARCHAR(MAX),
    @password VARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
        SELECT [dbo].[User].[Id],[dbo].[User].[Username] FROM [dbo].[User] 
WHERE username=@username AND password=@password
```

This is my method:

```
 public class UserBL
    {
        string conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
        public int CheckUserLogin(UserL User)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conexion))
            {
                SqlCommand comObj = new SqlCommand("spLogin", con);
                comObj.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comObj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", User.UserName));
                comObj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", User.Password));
                con.Open();
                return Convert.ToInt32(comObj.ExecuteScalar());
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my User class:

```
 public class UserL
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

And im checking if the user exited by id With Ajax but I need to create sessions, and in order to do that I need

Comment: You should use `comObj.ExecuteScalar()` (which will return only 1 value) but you need to use a [SqlCommand.ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: your method itself returns `int` so I don't know how you want to return both

Comment: From what I see: `ExecuteScalar` returns single record, to return multiple records perform `ExecuteReader` and iterate through `Read` method. Also, change method return type to a collection if `int` is not enough.

Comment: use *ExecuteReader*  you need to read multiple values. *ExecuteScalar* is used only when you need to read one and only one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Dictionary` to return the `UserName` and the `Id`, making the `Id` the key and `UserName` the value.

```
  public Dictionary<int, string> CheckUserLogin(UserL User)
        {
               var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conexion))
            {
                SqlCommand comObj = new SqlCommand("spLogin", con);
                comObj.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comObj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", User.UserName));
                comObj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", User.Password));
                con.Open();
               using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
               {
                    // Call Read before accessing data.
                    while (reader.Read())
                   {
                     dict.Add((int)reader["Id"],
                       reader["Username"]==DBNull.Value ?"":
                            (string)reader["Username"]);
                   }
               }
           }
           return dict;
       }
```

Comment: Thanks I was doing basically the same but with a List! :)

Comment: @RodolfoRodriguez i'm glad it helped

Comment: Why a `Dictionary`? A `Pair<int, string>` would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conexion))
        {
            SqlCommand comObj = new SqlCommand("spLogin", con);
            comObj.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comObj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", User.UserName));
            comObj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", User.Password));
            con.Open();
            var dr = comObj.ExecuteReader();
            while(dr.Read())
            {
              var userId = dr["Id"];
              var username = dr["Username"];
              // do something with your data....
            }
            con.Close();
        }
```

You *could* also use output parameters. Google it: https://www.google.no/search?q=stored+procedures+output+parameters&oq=stored+procedures+output+parameters

You are putting passwords as clear text in your database. **Don't do that.** Please read my article on Codeproject: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/425150/Beginners-guide-to-a-secure-way-of-storing-passwor

Comment: Thanks! Figured out I needed a list

Comment: @RodolfoRodriguez, hopefully your code was simplified and you're already doing this, but I strongly second the suggestion not to store clear text passwords.  Use [salted hashes](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=c%23+salted+hash) every time.

Answer (score 1):

use executereader because execute scalar return single value.

```
    public class UserBL
        {
            string conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
            public int CheckUserLogin(UserL User)
            {
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conexion))
                {
                    SqlCommand comObj = new SqlCommand("spLogin", con);
                    comObj.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    comObj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", User.UserName));
                    comObj.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", User.Password));
                    con.Open();
    var dr=comObj.ExecuteScalar();
 while(dr.read())
    {
    int userid=convert.toint16(dr[0]);
    string Password=dr[1].tostring();
    // now Manipulate as per as your requirment
    }
                }
            }
        }
```